# Create a method to pass the navigators and reload the navigators in that method

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, predicate

After I found out that navigation properties does not populate after insert operation in EF Code first , I decide to create a method to reload the navigations. Lets think we have two classes :

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id {get ; set;}
    public string Title {get ; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages {get ; set;}
}

public class Page
{
    public int Id {get ; set;}
    public string Content {get ; set;}
    public int BookId {get ; set;}
    public virtual Book Book {get ; set;}
}
```

and in the following code I have :

```
DbContext db = new DbContext()

Page p = new Page();
p.BookId = 1;
p.Content = "Sample Content";

db.Pages.Add(p);

db.SaveChanges();
db.Reload(p, rec => rec.Book); // Here is the wanted method
```

I tried this one , but I failed

```
public class DbContext : DbContext
{
    ///I know this method is wrong, I have no idea to fix it
    public T Reload<T>(T Obj, param Func<T,I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_I_SHOULD_PUT_HERE>[] predicates )
    {
        foreach(var item in predicates)
        {
             this.Entry<T>(Obj).Reference(item).Load();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anybody out there to help me complete this method ?

Comment: Have you tried either assigning a `Book` object to the `Page` `Book` property? Or adding a `Page` to the `Pages` collection? The call to `SaveChanges` should then populate the corresponding ID and corresponding navigation propery.

Comment: Yes , I tried , in Ef Code-First , it not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code to this , so the navigators populate correctly. So I do not need such mentioned method

```
DbContext db = new DbContext()

Page p = db.Pages.Create();
p.BookId = 1;
p.Content = "Sample Content";

db.Pages.Add(p);

db.SaveChanges();
db.Reload(p, rec => rec.Book);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im note sure I follow what you are trying to do.
But my first though is to recommend

The basic reload form is:

```
Context.Entry<TPoco>(poco).Reload();
```

You can also use Include form

```
var Qpocolist = Context.Set<TPoco>().Include(t=>t.Navprop).Where(t => t.Navprop.xyz=="xyz");
```

but perhaps it is just passing an array of prop expression you wanted a tip on.
You need to declare the method as generic for Poco and Property.

```
public void MyFancySetNavs<TPoco, TProp>(TPoco obj, params  Expression<Func<TPoco, TProp>>[] navProps) {
        foreach (var navPropExp in navProps) {
            // do ya thing...
        }

    }
```